# Server Error in '/' Application VB.NET

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I'm getting this error when I generate my report. It says

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ') GROUP BY cdr_id, cdr_extension_no, cdr_datetime, cdr_digits,
>   cdr_destination, ' at line 19

How can I solve this? I am new to vb.net programming.

This is my code:

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(reportFilter) Then
   daEmployee.SetWhereClause(String.Format("cdr_site_id = '{0}' AND a.employee_id IN({1}) AND cdr_datetime BETWEEN '{2}' AND '{3}' AND cdr_call_class_code = 'OUTGOING' AND cdr_call_type_id IN({4}) GROUP BY cdr_id, cdr_extension_no, cdr_datetime, cdr_digits, cdr_destination, cdr_charge_amount, cdr_duration_format, cdr_duration_number, cdr_charge_to, department_code, department_description ORDER BY employee_name", siteId, employeeId, startDateTime, endDateTime, callClass, callType))

Else
   daEmployee.SetWhereClause(String.Format("cdr_site_id = '{0}' AND a.employee_id IN({1}) AND cdr_datetime BETWEEN '{2}' AND '{3}' AND cdr_call_class_code = 'OUTGOING' AND cdr_call_type_id IN({4}) GROUP BY cdr_id, cdr_extension_no, cdr_datetime, cdr_digits, cdr_destination, cdr_charge_amount, cdr_duration_format, cdr_duration_number, cdr_charge_to, department_code, department_description ORDER BY employee_name", siteId, employeeId, startDateTime, endDateTime, callClass, callType))
End If
```

Comment: can you run query alone first ?\

Comment: I'm not familiar with the SetWhereClause method but you' giving it a GROUP BY as well, I guess that's not allowed.

Comment: Are there multiple call types in the {4} parameter, and how do you delimit them (ie, be sure to not leave a trailing comma), also, is that a string data type?

Comment: dump the whole query as it is sent. I'm guessing the problem is with the right parenthesis not having a matching left parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already solved my problem. The problem is on it's where clause. CDR date time is missing. I'm sorry for disturbing some of you. Thanks for your responses. This is my code:

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(reportFilter) Then
   daEmployee.SetWhereClause(String.Format("cdr_site_id = '{0}' and a.employee_id in ({1}) and cdr_datetime BETWEEN '{2}' AND '{3}' group by cdr_date,cdr_time,cdr_call_type_code ORDER BY employee_name", siteId, employeeId, startDateTime, endDateTime))
Else
   daEmployee.SetWhereClause(String.Format("cdr_site_id = '{0}' and a.employee_id in ({1}) and cdr_datetime BETWEEN '{2}' AND '{3}' group by cdr_date,cdr_time,cdr_call_type_code ORDER BY employee_name", siteId, employeeId, startDateTime, endDateTime))
End If
```

Comment: It was the IN() clause using the {4} parameter? You should clarify this in your answer if that was the case.